# parse acsm in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new to iOS development. I am working on an ePUB reader app for iPad.

The server sends me file with .acsm extension. Its an XML formatted file. Now I need to parse this acsm file and download the book.

The server side developer says that its working and he's able to download the ebook using Adobe Digital Editions.

What should I do to download the actual book and display it?

These are the contents of acsm file:

```
<fulfillmentToken fulfillmentType="buy" auth="user" xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/adept">
  <distributor>urn:uuid:861ac232-6f99-4be5-8b78-28d3aa1a1200</distributor>
  <operatorURL>http://litstage.cloudapp.net:8080/fulfillment/</operatorURL>
  <transaction>ACS4-6490845051477798803551940</transaction>
  <expiration>2012-12-05T10:57:33+00:00</expiration>
  <resourceItemInfo>
    <resource>urn:uuid:45c004e9-ff9f-4117-94b9-c6776176fa62</resource>
    <resourceItem>0</resourceItem>
    <metadata>
      <dc:title xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">The Divine Comedy</dc:title>
      <dc:creator xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">Dante, Alighieri</dc:creator>
      <dc:publisher xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">FeedBooks (www.feedbooks.com)</dc:publisher>
      <dc:identifier xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">urn:uuid:7d0300ba-2381-11dd-8c0f-001cc049a027</dc:identifier>
      <dc:format xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">application/epub+zip</dc:format>
      <dc:language xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">en</dc:language>
      <thumbnailURL>http://litstage.cloudapp.net:8080/media/45c004e9-ff9f-4117-94b9-c6776176fa62.jpg</thumbnailURL>
    </metadata>
    <licenseToken>
      <resource>urn:uuid:45c004e9-ff9f-4117-94b9-c6776176fa62</resource>
      <permissions>
        <display/>
        <excerpt/>
        <print/>
        <play/>
      </permissions>
    </licenseToken>
  </resourceItemInfo>
  <hmac>gGIGmkDLFpWda2dWchW3E46O9oA=</hmac>
</fulfillmentToken>
```

Comment: This is very broad question.  Is there a particular aspect of this you are getting stuck on?

Comment: I have done everything. Like loading list of books available in Library and Reading the ebook. I found an open source ePuab reader here: https://github.com/fedefrappi/AePubReader. But now when started integrating the server APIs to the project, I am stuck with loading the actual book contents :(

Comment: Have you solved your issue? how to extract book url from .ascm file parsing ?

Comment: @Hiren No! I switched to another project and someone else was then working on that project. And sorry for replying so late.

Comment: I am surprised, no one has found the solution in last 7 years. Is there any solution for this ?